# SQL Server - Incorrect syntax near ','

Tags: sql-server

I am inserting 250 items into my "Sticker" table, with a massive insert into statement.

I am getting this error on each "select" line during my insert into statement:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 19
>   Incorrect syntax near ','.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 21
>   Incorrect syntax near ','.

Here is my insert statement where the problem occurs:

```
INSERT INTO Stickers (Name, Category, Gender, Shop_ID, Url)
   SELECT 
       ('Flow Dress', 'Dress', 'F', 1, 'https://mmimages.blob.core.windows.net/stickers/amazingfemaledress.png')

   UNION ALL

   SELECT 
       ('On Point', 'Facial Hair', 'M', 7, 'https://mmimages.blob.core.windows.net/stickers/bestfacehairever.png')
```

This should give you enough information about the `Stickers` table:

```
CREATE TABLE [MirrorMirror].[dbo].[Stickers]
(
    [Sticker_ID] int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    [Name] varchar(40) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    [Category] varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    [Gender] char (1) NOT NULL,
    [Url] varchar(300) NOT NULL,

    [Shop_ID] int 
         FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [dbo].[Shops](Shop_Id) NOT NULL
)
```

And the `Shops` table:

```
CREATE TABLE [MirrorMirror].[dbo].[Shops] 
(
    [Shop_ID] int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    [Name] varchar(40) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
```

And finally, these shops are inserted into the `Shops` table BEFORE the stickers are inserted into the `Sticker` table (without error):

```
INSERT INTO Shops (Name)
       SELECT ('Glamour')
       UNION ALL
       SELECT ('Amber')
       UNION ALL
       SELECT('Nuvole Bianche')
       UNION ALL
       SELECT ('Cheapskate')
       UNION ALL
       SELECT ('North Shore')
       UNION ALL
       SELECT('Urban Style')
       UNION ALL
       SELECT('Fuzzy Beard Barbers')
       UNION ALL
       SELECT('Natural Beauty Salon');
```

Why am I getting the error for each insert into `Stickers` select statement?

**EDIT: I just changed the Url column to a varchar(300) as 60 characters was not enough. However I still get the errors.**

Comment: why do you put you columns in `() `?

Comment: Yeah, don't do that. Remove the `()`, that is your syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the parentheses:

```
INSERT INTO Stickers (Name, Category, Gender, Shop_ID, Url)
    SELECT 'Flow Dress', 'Dress', 'F', 1, 'https://mmimages.blob.core.windows.net/stickers/amazingfemaledress.png'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'On Point', 'Facial Hair', 'M', 7, 'https://mmimages.blob.core.windows.net/stickers/bestfacehairever.png'
```

Or, use `VALUES`:

```
INSERT INTO Stickers (Name, Category, Gender, Shop_ID, Url)
    VALUES ('Flow Dress', 'Dress', 'F', 1, 'https://mmimages.blob.core.windows.net/stickers/amazingfemaledress.png'),
           ('On Point', 'Facial Hair', 'M', 7, 'https://mmimages.blob.core.windows.net/stickers/bestfacehairever.png');
```

The parentheses are used for grouping a single expression, which is why you are getting an error in your construct.